# I want to convert arraylist of custom java object to hashmap by keeping key-value pair of arraylist same in the map

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, hashmap

This is my list I am fetching from db (It can be updated in db in future by addition of more variables  :

```
response

 {
   "nameField1"   : "nameLabel1",
    "numberField2": "numberLabel2"   
}
```

I want the result map<String, String> to look like this :

{nameField1=nameLabel1, numberField2=numberLabel2 }

Comment: what if 2 objects of the array have the same attribute names ?

Comment: Hey..sorry my bad..this array won't be having multiple objects. It will have added variables but no extra object @jhamon

Comment: Use a JSON library such as Jackson.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on [Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18157/jim-garrison)'s post, give this a look, [Baeldung - Using Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/java-convert-object-to-map#using-jackson).  This library should help you convert a generic object into a map.  Those objects being in an ArrayList, or really any form of list, doesn't make it much harder.

Comment: Thank you wolginm & @Jim Garrison. It worked like a charm.